# Solving ODE with RK method and plotting

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following ode

$i\dot{\phi_n}(t)=-\phi_{n+1}(t)-\phi_{n-1}(t)+\frac{g~ \phi_n(t)}{1+|\phi_n(t)|^2}$ with I.C. $\phi(0)=-2\cos(2.5)$ and $g=1$.

However, I am unable to produce the "close to desired" plot of $|\phi_n(t=fixed)|$ y-axis vs $n$ on x-axis.
What I wrote in the code is the following

```
k = 2.5;
n = 1000;
syms2 = Table[Subscript[\[Alpha], i], {i, n}];
For[j = 1, j < n + 1, j++, syms2[[j]] = 0];
syms2[[(n/2)]] = 1; syms2[[n/2 + 1]] = 1;
Subscript[\[Phi], 0][t_] := Subscript[\[Phi], 1][t];
Subscript[\[Phi], n + 1][t_] := Subscript[\[Phi], n][t];
eqns = Table[{Sqrt[-1]*
      Subscript[\[Phi], i]'[t] == -Subscript[\[Phi], i + 1][t] - 
      Subscript[\[Phi], i - 1][t] + ((
       syms2[[i]]*Subscript[\[Phi], i][t])/(
       1 + Abs[Subscript[\[Phi], i][t]]^2)), 
    Subscript[\[Phi], i][0] == -2*Cos[k]}, {i, n}];
vars = Table[Subscript[\[Phi], i][t], {i, n}];
sol = NDSolve[eqns, vars, {t, 0, 250}, 
   Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", "StiffnessTest" -> False}, 
   MaxSteps -> \[Infinity], AccuracyGoal -> 8, PrecisionGoal -> 8];
Plot1 = ListPlot[Table[Abs[vars /. First[%]], {t, 0, 250}], 
  PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> False]
```

I don't know how to get a snapshot at a particular time, as I mentioned above.

Comment: The equations in your code is inconsistent with the ones shown in $\LaTeX$, please double check them.

Comment: @xzczd I think the only thing which I did not mention in description is that I have two sites $n=500$ and $n=501$ where the term with $g$ has a contribution, otherwise it is zero for all remaining sites. Is there anything else you suspect? I thought the code reflects the exact same equation?

Comment: For example, `-Subscript[\[Phi], i + 1][t] - 
      Subscript[\[Phi], i - 1][t]` vs $-\phi_{n+1}(t)-\phi_{n+1}(t)$.

Comment: @xzczd is it not the correct way to write this?

Comment: I have not found an alternate way to write this..

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eA3aR.png

Comment: @xzczd I understand what you mean, but could you instead please write those two words which would correct it?

Comment: I can't, because nobody except you knows which version is correct, and it's not impossible that both versions are incorrect. The only thing I can do is to point out the inconsistency.

Comment: @xzczd I see.. What would I do if I want to write time dependent functions at discrete points? like I did.. say I have a lattice of 4 sites, so I would want to write (for coding)  $\phi_n(t)$ = `Subscript[\[Phi], n][t]` , then for the next site I would like to transform $\phi_{n+1}(t)$ into a code, which I will write `Subscript[\[Phi], n + 1][t]` whats wrong with that? Is it inconsistent?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CNhm.png

Comment: Ohh.. my mistake... Sorry I didn't catch your meaning.. I just corrected it..

Comment: Still, there exists inconsistency in your post, please triple check it.

Comment: Why do you need to use `Method->ExplicitRungeKutta`?  Other methods usually work better for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
tm = 1000; k = 2.5;
n = 1000;
Table[syms2[i] = 0, {i, n}];
syms2[n/2] = 1; syms2[n/2 + 1] = 1;
\[Phi][n + 1][t_] := \[Phi][n][t]
\[Phi][0][t_] := \[Phi][1][t]
eqns = Table[{I*
      D[\[Phi][i][t], t] == -\[Phi][i + 1][t] - \[Phi][i - 1][t] + 
      syms2[i]*\[Phi][i][t]/(1 + Abs[\[Phi][i][t]]^2), \[Phi][i][
      0] == -2*Cos[k]}, {i, n}];
vars = Table[Abs[\[Phi][i][t]], {i, n}];
sol = NDSolveValue[eqns, vars, {t, 0, tm}];


L = ListAnimate[
  Table[ListPlot[sol, PlotRange -> {0, 2.5}, ColorFunction -> Hue, 
    Joined -> True, Frame -> True], {t, 0, tm, 5}]]
```

[image: fig1]

Comment: How did you create the GIF movie of this in order to post it?

Comment: @Moo I use `Export["C:\\Users\\name\\Desktop\\Fig1.gif", L, AnimationRepetitions -> Infinity]`

Comment: @AlexTrounev Thanks. just to confirm, x-axis is $n$ and y-axis is $|\phi_n|$?

Comment: Secondly, could you please tell me how to change the x-axis from "0,1000" to "-500,+500", i.e., then I think the function `syms2` will also be modified. Thanks.

Comment: @AtoZ Yes, x-axis is `{i,1,n}` and y-axis is `Table[Abs[\[Phi][i][t]], {i, n}]` at `n=1000`

Comment: @AtoZ Do you want a solution with broken symmetry, for example, `n=500;` 'Table[syms2[i] = 0, {i,-n, n}]; syms2[n/2] = 1; syms2[n/2 + 1] = 1;`?

Comment: @AlexTrounev Absolutely right, the symmetry is broken w.r.t the central two sites. so perhaps `syms2[n/2] = 1`  `syms2[n/2 + 1] = 2` could be a choice. However,  I think to get close to the desired result the I.C. `\[Phi][i][0]` should be initiated at the first site, i.e., n=-500, or n=0, for the version in your answer. Because it seems that the initial condition initiates at the central sites and then spreads to the left and right?

Comment: @AtoZ To reproduce your pictures you need to know the parameters and the initial conditions. Where did you get them from?

Comment: @AlexTrounev got it. Thanks :-)